# "Default" docker machine does not exist on Linux when Docker daemon is running

Tags: linux, docker, docker-machine

I'm running Docker on Linux Manjaro. No problem with running and using the service:

```
[luqo33@ltarasiewicz-pc containers]$ systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2016-12-23 20:46:31 CET; 26s ago
```

However, `docker-machine ls` will always show this:

```
[luqo33@ltarasiewicz-pc containers]$ docker-machine ls
NAME   ACTIVE   DRIVER   STATE   URL   SWARM   DOCKER   ERRORS
```

and

```
[luqo33@ltarasiewicz-pc containers]$ docker-machine env default
Host does not exist: "default"
```

Why isn't there the 'default' machine available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have installed docker on Linux, you can access it directly on the host with `docker ps` or any other docker commands. You will need to either run these commands as root (sudo) or add your user to the docker group for access to the docker socket.

Docker machine is used to quickly spin up cloud and virtual machine instances of docker, so it's not needed when you have installed it directly on the Linux host.

Comment: This led to the correct fix. Using `docker ps` found I had permission issues, which further research is fixed by doing: `sudo groupadd docker` and `sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create it, like this:

```
$ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
...
...
...
To see how to connect Docker to this machine, run: docker-machine env default


$: docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
default   -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v1.12.1


$: docker-machine env default
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users/blahblah/.docker/machine/machines/default"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
```

EDIT: You can also use other virtualization providers like Fusion, Hyper-V etc.

Comment: I'm not using Virtualbox to run Docker on linux. The Docker daemon is listeing on a unix socket. I know that you have to use a VM on Mac and Windows, but it does not seem to be relevant for Linux.

Comment: @luqo33 Using or not using VirtualBox to run Docker on Linux has nothing to do with running Docker Machine on Linux. The purpose of Docker Machine is to create servers, install Docker on them, and configure the Docker client. That's it. Those servers can be local VMs (which used to be the only way of running Docker on non-Linux platforms) using VirtualBox, Hyper-V etc. or cloud servers like AWS or Azure using vendor specific drivers. My answer applies even if you are running Linux. Read the official documentation to gain a better understanding of Docker Machine.